# Unresolved issues in android studios with android device info library

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I cannot resolved the issue with android device info, when I hover above the build.androidId, it says as shown in image below:

[image]

I have also copy pasted, the codes section

```
 Map<String, dynamic> _readAndroidBuildData(AndroidDeviceInfo build) {
      return <String, dynamic>{
        'version.securityPatch': build.version.securityPatch,
        'version.sdkInt': build.version.sdkInt,
        'version.release': build.version.release,
        'version.previewSdkInt': build.version.previewSdkInt,
        'version.incremental': build.version.incremental,
        'version.codename': build.version.codename,
        'version.baseOS': build.version.baseOS,
        'board': build.board,
        'bootloader': build.bootloader,
        'brand': build.brand,
        'device': build.device,
        'display': build.display,
        'fingerprint': build.fingerprint,
        'hardware': build.hardware,
        'host': build.host,
        'id': build.id,
        'manufacturer': build.manufacturer,
        'model': build.model,
        'product': build.product,
        'supported32BitAbis': build.supported32BitAbis,
        'supported64BitAbis': build.supported64BitAbis,
        'supportedAbis': build.supportedAbis,
        'tags': build.tags,
        'type': build.type,
        'isPhysicalDevice': build.isPhysicalDevice,
        'androidId': build.androidId,
        'systemFeatures': build.systemFeatures,
      };
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect to find in `build.androidId`? Have you check the API documentation of the package?

Comment: Hi @PeterKoltai , actually this coding was given to me to execute, this was my senior's coding. so I pretty much don't understand what he wants to do with the build.android, I have checked the package of Android Device Info, but inside the package, it doesn't have the specific build.android syntax